# Keyboard events in terminal

Tags: perl, events, terminal, keypress, keydown

I'm going to write terminal based game. It will be realtime, so I need to display animation and read keyboard events in the same time. How can I do that? In JavaScript I would make a loop displaying the state of game and attach events to custom keys. But I have no Idea how to do something like that in Perl and terminal. It must be nonblocking and it must allows to react on multiple keys at the same time.

Comment: And you have chosen to do this in Perl because... ?

Comment: Because I have to:). It's academic project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `POE::Wheel::TermKey` and it is perfect solution of my problem:). Don't forget to install libtermkey before installing this module.

http://metacpan.org/pod/POE::Wheel::TermKey

http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libtermkey/

If you have problems with installing `Term::TermKey` module, look here:
[Installing Term::TermKey returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287071/installing-termtermkey-returns-error). libtermkey is  quite new so it's not available in repositories of many Linux distributions.

Answer (score 7):

Curses::UI is a terminal-based widget set with keyboard events, it is probably a good bet.